# c# Different behavior of saving user settings on different machines

Tags: c#, settings

I am confused with how the settings are user settings are stored in different machines.

Lets say I have the following user settings stored im my app.config:

```
   <userSettings>
    <StationAgent.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="AAA" serializeAs="String">
        <value>11</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="BBB" serializeAs="String">
        <value>22</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="CCC" serializeAs="String">
        <value>33</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="DDD" serializeAs="String">
        <value>44</value>
      </setting>
    </StationAgent.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
```

In the code I change the value of "AAA" to 666 and save it and I read the "BBB" value.

On my local machine (Windows 7) the settings that are stored in the "Local" folder in user.config are

```
   <userSettings>
    <StationAgent.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="AAA" serializeAs="String">
        <value>666</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="BBB" serializeAs="String">
        <value>22</value>
      </setting>
    </StationAgent.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
```

When the same code runs on the server (Windows Server 2007) the config file look like:

```
<userSettings>
<StationAgent.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="AAA" serializeAs="String">
    <value>666</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="BBB" serializeAs="String">
    <value></value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="CCC" serializeAs="String">
    <value></value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="DDD" serializeAs="String">
    <value></value>
  </setting>
</StationAgent.Properties.Settings>
```

As you can see in the first case the only touched values stored in different file, in the second case all variables were saved with default values except the "AAA".

My question is why is this difference? What am I doing wrong? And how I can fix this?

If this helps I do work always with Settings.Default and make Settings.Default.Save().

Comment: Under which account are you running the code on the server? (I assume on your local machine, you're using your personal user account).

Comment: Yes, on my local machine I run as a regular user and on the server the code is run as a service under Administrator. Why this should change the behavior of the Save() ?

Comment: I can't answer why it _should_ change the behavior. But it certainly might, since the Administrator account has more access to the file system than other accounts. Also, something to keep in mind, the .NET runtime that is present on Server OS versions is actually different than the client runtime found on a workstation. Unfortunately, I don't know all of the specific differences off the top of my head, but I do know they exist. So for further investigation you might want to do searches in the documentation with the above in mind.